# MVC Areas: How should I map my routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I wanted to organize my solution and I looked into areas but it seems the: **The request for '*ControllerName*' has found the following matching controllers...** error is getting famous.

**I added an `Admin` area and my project's folder structure looks like this:**

- Areas

  - Admin

    - Controllers
    - HomeController
  - AdminAreaRegistration.cs
- Controllers

  - HomeController

**On my AdminAreaRegistration file I have this:**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**And I'm doing this when registering my routes:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home", 
    "Home/Index", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

**I've read [here](http://suhair.in/Blog/Aspnet-MVC-Areas-in-depth-Part-2) to do this on my `Application_Start` method:**

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("X.Web.Controllers");
```

**Sadly it didn't fix the error. Then I read [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/asp-net-mvc2-preview-2-areas-and-routes.aspx) to add the namespace of the default (root) controller is in, in the RegisterRoutes method.**

I know areas is all about routing, the folders are merely needed, but they're useful though.

I would like to know how can I map my routes to a specific `HomeController` in this case, one is in `X.Web.Controllers` and the other one is in `X.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers`. Plus I would like to know if the links can be generated with an `@Html.RouteLink` helper instead of `ActionLink`, because in **all** the examples I've read so far the links are being generated using the `ActionLink` method... which makes me doubt.

I'll appreciate any help/guidance provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon a similar problem, and as I couldn't find a 'clean' solution, I ended up renaming one of the HomeControllers - that should help.

As for the links - yes it is possible to generate them, you need to add the area name to one of the parameters (routeValues), so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "Admin" })
```

Comment: Chris: that is, actually, my plan b. Renaming should get it fixed.